# C# How to query Windows DNS Server for a rrecord without using WMI

Tags: c#, .net, dns

Is there a way that I can search a Dns server for an record without using WMI to make the connection to the Dns server using .NET 4,5?

I have this fully working with Wmi in .NET 4.5 but find it to be way too slow (even when caching the connections).  It's too inconsistent.  Some search queries are 2 seconds while others are over 100 seconds.

And as far as I know I can't optimize the query any further.

```
Query:  string query = "SELECT * FROM " + propertiesStruct.Table + " WHERE ContainerName = '" + domain + "' AND OwnerName ='" + name + "." + domain + "'";
```

So I'm looking for a way to connect to the dns server, query it for a dns record by name and domain and get back the same/similar data as a WMI query if possible.

I've looked at .NET 4.5 System.Net.Dns class and methods but find it does not give enough information back.  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Information I'm looking to get back are: Example -

DNS Record fqdn - stackoverflow.com

DNS Record Name - stackoverflow

DNS Domain/Zone - com

DNS Record value - 198.252.206.140

DNS Record type - A/AAAA/CNAME/PTR

DNS Record ttl - 3600

Even if it returns all the records with the same fqdn but different values because of it being a different record type that is fine I can filter the results manually for the type I'm looking for.

Closest thing I have found is a Linux dig but this has to be done in .net on a windows server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can use p/invoke, then there's the DNSAPI library/DLL.  See [DNSAPI on pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dnsapi.dnsquery) .  Some of the options suggest that the DnsQuery method *can* use the dns-cache, and also that use of the cache can be turned off.  I've used this API successfully, but we warned, it's a pretty low level.  As an example, if you want to do reverse lookup, you probably have to assemble the query explicitly (that is, for 192.168.0.1, use a query of type PTR for "1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" ).